# Should one ever use \bigskip?

Tags: paragraphs, vertical-spacing

I am wondering whether one is ever justified in using \bigskip in LaTeX (specifically in overleaf)? I have recently drastically reduced my use of it, due to my teacher's recommendation. But I tend to resort to it, if my last paragraph did not end in mathmode. Is there someway else to get around using \bigskip, when one has not ended the previous paragraph in mathmode?

Since the bot asked for clarification; is there a way to get around using blank line + \bigskip when wanting a new paragraph, when one did not end the previous paragraph in mathmode.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This question is unrelated to Overleaf, so I changed the tags. (Overleaf hosts a standard texlive tex so it's just the machine where you run tex, you would get the same output wherever you ran the same tex code)

Comment: Your edit to add a final comment is a bit strange as `\bigskip` doesn't  generate a new paragraph, you have to end the paragraph (typically with a blank line in the source) before adding the skip _between_ paragraphs.

Comment: I have edited my edit.

Comment: `\bigskip` closes current paragraph outside LaTeX. This is much more natural behavior.

Comment: You've gotten some good answers, but I think it would have been useful for you to provide a more concrete instance where you think `\bigskip` is necessary but your teacher doesn't.

Comment: Due to David Carlisles answer, almost never.

Comment: If one should never use \bigskip, what do see as the purpose of \bigskip?
Are you really Asking why Tex has \bigskip, or what?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're describing the effect you get with

```
\usepackage{parskip}
```

What's most certain is that you don't want `\bigskip` after every paragraph not ending in a display. Remove all of them and load that package.

After staring again at your document and comparing it to books you take off the shelf papers, it will be very easy to comment out `\usepackage{parskip}` and get a good-looking document.

If your aim is not to space every paragraph, but just some of them, ***do resist*** the temptation as per your teacher's recommendations. It's really a rare case that spacing a particular paragraph from the preceding one conveys meaning to the reader.

Answer (score 18):

Never say never, but in general explict spacing in a document should be avoided. `\bigskip` is perhaps better than `\vspace{2cm}` but not much. Especially as you hint on using it every paragraph. Paragraph spacing should be set up as a document default to ensure consistency, not applied to every paragraph individually.

`\bigskip` can be used sometimes as an "anonymous section" providing a break that does not, for whatever reason, need a section heading, but spacing every paragraph should not be done via markup on each paragraph but by setting `\parskip` (eg by use of the `parskip` package).

Comment: Thanks, \parskip seems like a good solution. How do you write in code-style? (I am new here)

Comment: inline uses single backtick `\`foo\``  `foo` code blocks use three `\`\`\`` (but you can not use that in comments)

Comment: @Ben123 there is a "help" link in the bottom right of every coment text box with a syntax overview:-)

Comment: @Ben123 Or you can highlight blocks (not in comments) and ctrl+k.

Comment: Does this apply to using it in macro definitions? I always figured that would be OK. Also, `\bigskip` is invaluable if you're producing a form which needs to look as if it was produced in Word for printing on carbon triplicate dot-matrix.

Comment: @cfr well that depends what your macro is. If it's a kind of anonymous spaced section or spaced vertical display, then sure that's fine, but if it's a styled paragraph sort of thing then using parskip or a styled display object such as `center`  to get the same parameterised vertical space as other display objects then less so. What's Word? is that some kind of vim clone?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Some software the uni pushes as 'emacs for the 21st century'. Apparently, the built-in therapist inspired the old paperclip. Not sure what you mean about parskip/center making bigskip less OK? I use it where I want a clear but unobtrusive break mostly (except for form-emulation - typographic quality isn't really a priority there, but substituting skips generates fewer warnings than the original conversion generates). Actually, I just discovered I use it less than I thought.

Answer (score 5):

> I am wondering whether one is *ever* justified in using `\bigskip` in LaTeX
> [emphasis added]

I find it helpful and legitimate to employ `\bigskip` and its sibling directives, `\medskip` and `\smallskip`, as *fine-tuning instruments* when creating figures with vertically stacked `subfigures`.

- By default, no vertical whitespace is inserted between stacked `subfigure` (or `subtable`) environments. This can lead to an outcome where the upper subfigure's caption (its "subcaption"?), if placed below the graph, is visually closer to the graph below it than to its "real" graph (the one above it). The same problem occurs for stacked `subtable` environemnts and their associated subcaptions.
- The way to deal with this situation is to add some discretionary vertical whitespace between the `subfigure` environments.  Depending on the sizes of graphs/tables and the lengths and placement of the associated captions, either `\bigskip` or `\medskip` is the right tool for this fine-tuning operation.

The following code and associated screenshot illustrate the usefulness of the `\bigskip` directive for fine-tuning purposes: Without it, the visual gap between the first graph and its caption would be larger than that between the first subcaption and the second graph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % for '\includegraphics' macro
\usepackage{subcaption}     % for 'subfigure' environment

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}

\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}
\caption{A first subfigure}
\end{subfigure}

\bigskip % <-- or "\medskip"
\begin{subfigure}{\textwidth}
\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{fig1}
\caption{A second subfigure}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{A figure with two subfigures}

\end{figure}

\end{document}
```